# mysql insert in to database - no data passed to db

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm sending a form to a php page, which then saves to a mysql database. The code seems to execute without errors, but no values are saved to the database.

Have I missed something out from my code?

Form:

```
<form action="newcourse.php" method="post">
<input name="title" type="text" id="title" value="">
<br /><br />
  <input name="location" type="text" id="location" value="">
<br /><br />
<input name="datestart" type="text" id="datestart" value="">
<br /><br />
<input name="dateend" type="text" id="dateend" value=""><br /><br />
<select name="noofweeks" id="noofweeks">
  <option value="1" selected>1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
  <option value="6">6</option>
  <option value="7">7</option>
  <option value="8">8</option>
  <option value="9">9</option>
  <option value="10">10</option>
  <option value="11">11</option>
  <option value="12">12</option>
</select><br /><br />
<select name="wheelchair" id="wheelchair">
  <option value="yes">yes</option>
  <option value="no" selected>no</option>
</select>
<br /><br />
<input name="time" type="text" id="time" value=""><br /><br />
<input name="courseleader" type="text" id="courseleader" value=""><br /><br />
<input name="pack" type="hidden" id="pack" value="participants_pack.pdf">
<input name="price" type="text" id="price" value=""><br /><br />
<input name="group" type="text" id="group" value=""><br /><br />
<input name="numberofplaces" type="text" id="numberofplaces" value=""><br /><br />
<select name="bookings" id="bookings">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
  <option value="6">6</option>
  <option value="7">7</option>
  <option value="8">8</option>
  <option value="9">9</option>
  <option value="10">10</option>
  <option value="11">11</option>
  <option value="12">12</option>
  <option value="0" selected>0</option>
</select>
<br /><br />
<br /><br />
<input name="submit" type="submit" value="Save"></p></form>
```

Save to mysql database:

```
<?php
$title=$_POST['title'];
$location=$_POST['location'];
$datestart=$_POST['datestart'];
$dateend=$_POST['dateend'];
$noofweeks=$_POST['noofweeks'];
$wheelchair=$_POST['wheelchair'];
$time=$_POST['time'];
$courseleader=$_POST['courseleader'];
$pack=$_POST['pack'];
$price=$_POST['price'];
$group=$_POST['group'];
$numberofplaces=$_POST['numberofplaces'];
$bookings=$_POST['bookings'];
//
require_once('connecttodatabase.php');
//
mysql_query("INSERT INTO courses (title, location, datestart, dateend, noofweeks, wheelchair, time, courseleader, pack, price, group, numberofplaces, bookings)  VALUES('$title', '$location', '$datestart', '$dateend', '$noofweeks', '$wheelchair', '$time', '$courseleader', '$pack', '$price', '$group', '$numberofplaces', '$bookings')");
mysql_close();
echo "Database updated!";
?>
```

The connecttodatabase.php just connects to the database and works for other scripts, so I know this isn't the problem.

Comment: What happens if you echo out your SQL and run it straight in the database?

Comment: Where is the code where you define these variables: VALUES('$title', '$location', '$datestart', '$dateend', '$noofweeks', '$wheelchair', '$time', '$courseleader', '$pack', '$price', '$group', '$numberofplaces', '$bookings')"

Comment: I can manually insert data to the DB without problems.

Comment: are you using register_globals?  And also you do not want to run this in production, since little bobby tables can ruin your day.

Comment: `mysql_query(...) or die(mysql_error());` <-- Always! Every time! Check for errors!

Comment: Learn about properly preserving SQL syntax! [The Great Escapism (Or: What You Need To Know To Work With Text Within Text)](http://kunststube.net/escapism/)

Comment: you should always initiate connection to the database on the top of the page

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the [*red box*](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide which, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help you. If you pick PDO, [here is good tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `time` and `group` too as a column name which is a reserved sql keyword, use back ticks around column names.. And I am re-writing your code a lil..moreover dont use name of submit as submit, use something else like `any_name //Change anyname to whatever` you like

```
<?php
require_once('connecttodatabase.php');

if(isset($_POST['any_name'])) {
$title=$_POST['title'];
$location=$_POST['location'];
$datestart=$_POST['datestart'];
$dateend=$_POST['dateend'];
$noofweeks=$_POST['noofweeks'];
$wheelchair=$_POST['wheelchair'];
$time=$_POST['time'];
$courseleader=$_POST['courseleader'];
$pack=$_POST['pack'];
$price=$_POST['price'];
$group=$_POST['group'];
$numberofplaces=$_POST['numberofplaces'];
$bookings=$_POST['bookings'];

   if(mysql_query("INSERT INTO courses (title, location, datestart, dateend, noofweeks, wheelchair, `time`, courseleader, pack, price, `group`, numberofplaces, bookings)  VALUES('$title', '$location', '$datestart', '$dateend', '$noofweeks', '$wheelchair', '$time', '$courseleader', '$pack', '$price', '$group', '$numberofplaces', '$bookings')")) {
     echo 'success';
      } else {
         echo 'Failed'.' '.mysql_error();
       }
    }
?>
```

P.S Start using `mysqli` - **[Reference](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)**

Comment: Thank you Mr. Alien! I renamed the group and time variables and it worked perfectly! Thanks again for your help! :)

Comment: @williamsongibson you welcome, and it is better to ignore reserved keywords..happy coding :)

Comment: Yup, I'm going to look for a list of reserved words now! :)

Answer (score 1):

You have to grab those variables from POST, e.g:

```
$title = $_POST['title'];
```

Ok your edit shows you are doing that, I'll update this if I find anything.

I'd suggest looking at Bondye's answer and using:

```
mysql_query(...) or die(mysql_error());
```

So you can see the error message returned from the SQL database.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
<?php
$title = $_POST['title']
//and rest

mysql_query("INSERT INTO courses (title, location,....) VALUES('{$title}', '{$location}', '{$datestart}', '{$dateend}'.....')");

?>
```

Comment: hmmm your right... I thought maybe that was mistake..